# Powershell script for web deploy package to IIS server (Remote)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, powershell

I am a developer but I don't have permission to deploy a package. If I provide a `power shell script` and `Web deployment package (.zip)` to my network admin, he will deploy it to the server.

Power shell needs to ask `path to deploy` (IIS web site path). The script has to pickup WDP, extract it, and deploy to given path on the IIS server.

```
Example: ExampleMVC.zip (WDP)
 path: \\iisprod1\inetpub\wwwroot\iapps
```

Now I want deploy this package to that path. How can I we do that?

Answer (score 0):

ZIP deploy package usually comes with a .cmd file (and some xml files too) which should be ran with `/Y` parameter in order to deploy the package on the current computer's IIS web server. If you want to change the web application path, do it while you building the ZIP package in your visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

It be easier to just use a batch script. I would add the path's you want to deploy to in a separate file. It could be done like this:

```
@echo off
set "scriptPath=/where/the/files/are"
for /F %%a IN (deployment-list.txt) DO (
     REM Will prompt for password and set T: (temp) drive to path
     net use T: \\%%a /u:administrator *
     copy %scriptPath%\ExampleMVC.zip t:\
     net use t: /d
)
```

Or with just one path and no loop:

```
 REM Will prompt for password and set T: (temp) drive to path
 net use T: \\iisprod1\inetpub\wwwroot\iapps /u:administrator *
 copy \path\to\file\ExampleMVC.zip t:\
 net use t: /d
```

Also if you would like to have the extracted content, simply extract it first and copy the contents over alternatively like this:

```
 REM Will prompt for password and set T: (temp) drive to path
 net use T: \\iisprod1\inetpub\wwwroot\iapps /u:administrator *
 copy \path\to\file\ExampleMVC\* t:\
 net use t: /d
```